# How can I start MAIN activity with the help of <intent-filter>?

Tags: android, intentfilter

When I declare my main activity in this maner:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
          <action android:name="com.package.name.MyActivity"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

then I get an error `No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.package.name.MyActivity flg=0x24000000 }` when I am using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.package.name.MyActivity");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

If do not use `Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);` how can I do this with the help of `action` for `<intent-filter>`

**Didn't help:**

```
 <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
      <action android:name="com.package.name.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.package.name.VIEW");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Create a custom 'action' such as `com.package.name.ACTION_VIEW` and as Jeffery Blatman advises, remove the 'action' for `com.package.name.MyActivity`. You then just use your custom action to start the `Activity`.

Comment: I've changed the code, but it didn't help me. where I made ​​a mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to specify two intent filters:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.package.name.MyAction"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then you can start the activity using the action name:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.package.name.MyAction");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

or the class name:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent("com.package.name.MyAction");
context.startActivity(intent);` didn't help (_No Activity found to handle Intent_) :(

Using class name work, but I want to use **action name**

Comment: @Svyatoslav: I am very confident that the answer given here is correct, and that you implemented the solution incorrectly.

Comment: @CommonsWare I found that it works by using **action name** when second `<intent-filter>` contains <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> else.

Comment: @Svyatoslav: Ah, yes, my apologies. `startActivity()` always adds `CATEGORY_DEFAULT` to an `Intent` if there is no other category specified. Hence, an `<intent-filter>` for an `<activity>` always needs a `<category>`, whether `DEFAULT` or something else.

Comment: Answer edited to add the default category. Sorry for having forgotten that.

Answer (score 1):

the `name` attribute in the `action` tag is the name of the action, not the name of your activity. remove the line,

```
  <action android:name="com.package.name.MyActivity"/>
```

since the intent filter tag is under your activity's tag, the system already understands that it's applied to that activity.

Comment: So I'll have two lines `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>`. What does I must wright in java code?

Comment: you do not need to write anything in java. that intent filter will show a launcher icon linked to that activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your class name isn't `com.package.name.MyActivity`, it's `com.package.name.general.MyActivity`.

An easy way to avoid this mistake is to create your new Intent using a class instead of a package name.  You can use auto-complete to fill in the right class.

You say you don't want to create the Intent by specifying the class.  I wonder why not -- I think it's a good way to go.